# How to make an optional strong parameters key but filter nested params?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have this in my controller:

```
params.require(:item).permit!
```

Let's assume this rspec spec, which works as expected:

```
put :update, id: @item.id, item: { name: "new name" }
```

However, the following causes `ActionController::ParameterMissing`:

```
put :update, id: @item.id, item: nil
```

It has to do with controller macros that I use for other actions and through which I cannot control the params being sent (the macros checks for user credentials, so I don't really care about actually testing an `#update` action, rather I just test before_filters for it).

So my question is: **How do I make `params[:item]` optional, yet still filter attributes within it if it's present?**

Comment: Some good ideas at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9534 . Basically the suggestion is to use `#fetch` instead of `#require` since it has a second parameter for a default, e.g.: `params.fetch(:item, {}).permit!`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

What about:

`params.require(:item).permit! if params[:item]`

You cannot require an optional parameter. That is contradictory.

Edit: as mtjhax mentioned in his comment, there is advice from [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9534) to use `fetch` instead: `params.fetch(:item, {}).permit!`

Comment: I think you misunderstood his question. It's perfectly valid to want to require the main container (:item) while making some of its internal sub-attributes optional only, which aside from using `params.require(:item).permit!` (which permits any parameters as long as they're within `:item` and `:item` exists doesn't seem possible in a granular way.

Comment: @OlivierLacan reading it back, I think you might be correct, though I'm now confused why he accepted my answer if it didn't resolve his problem.

Comment: `params.require(:item).permit! if params[:item]` does not work as it doesn't drill down into the `:item` hash and can't be passed into `new` for instance. `fetch(...)` works like a charm.