# Rails params.require on empty hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, strong-parameters

In one of my controllers I have the line:

```
params.require(:ad).permit(permitted_array)
```

`params[:ad]` is a hash. When permitted keys are present in this hash, this line works fine. When `params[:ad]` is an empty hash, the above line fails.

Example: With `params` being

```
{"ad"=>{}, "controller"=>"ads", "action"=>"create"}
```

I get this error after `params.require(:ad)` is called:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing:
   param is missing or the value is empty: advertiser
```

But this works fine:

```
[2] pry()> params
=> {"ad"=>{"name"=>"kjj", "ad_type_id"=>1, "fee"=>"9", "click_attr"=>"8", "imp_attr"=>"7"}, "controller"=>"ads", "action"=>"create"}
[3] pry()> params.require(:ad).permit(permitted_array)
=> {"name"=>"kjj", "ad_type_id"=>1, "fee"=>"9", "click_attr"=>"8", "imp_attr"=>"7"}
```

How can I get this line to accept an empty hash?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687506/how-to-make-an-optional-strong-parameters-key-yet-still-filter-params-nested-in

Answer (score 12):

Make the params `require` conditional, require the key only if it is present, like this:

```
params.require(:ad).permit(permitted_array) if params[:ad].present?
```